# Install vtk with pip in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, vtk

I tried installing vtk via pip in Windows, but it returned the following error.

```sh
python -m pip install vtk
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk
```

Platform: Windows 10 (64 bit)
Python: 3.8 (64 bit)
pip: 20.1

[image]

Comment: VTK installs in Python 3.9 now with the same pip command

Answer (score 1):

It seems that python 3.8 is not supported in vtk yet.

https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17670

You should try lowering your python version to 3.6 before installing it.

Answer (score 1):

the error in your case is because the latest version of vtk currently available on pypi 8.1.2 does not support python==3.8.

Try installing using python==3.7